# no google play service library in sdk manager/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sdk, admob, google-play-services

i have devloped two apps.
i want to monetize both of them with ad-mob(google ad service).
i know that legacy ad-mob has ended and we need to use google play services to include ads in our app.

THE PROBLEM IS there is no google play services library in sdk manager/extras folder.
i am using adt bundle eclipse...
i updated the build tools and other stuff but still can't able to find it.

can somebody post a link for the google play service 5.0 zip file.??

i tried to google is what i found is 4.x.x which doesn't has ad service.
every help will be apriciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You should really try to figure out why your SDK manager is not letting you download Google Play services (since there is an immiment update coming)...but in the meantime, here is the link to the latest version (R19):

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip

Here's how to install it like the SDK Manger would:

- Extract the zip somewhere (it will create a folder called `google-play-services`).
- Rename this folder to `google_play_services` (note the "_" instead of "-").
- Copy/move this new `google_play_services` folder to `(SDK)\extras\google\`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your Android SDK folder and tell it to install "Google Play services"

[image: Showing which package to install]

Once you do that, then when you go to your

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google

(or wherever you have yours installed)

folder, it should have a "google_play_services" folder which is what you need. :-)

Note: if you don't have the android sdk installed then you need to install it anyhow since you will need that for running eclipse anyhow

Comment: actully in extras folder i only have two check boxes like option
1> android support library
2> intel x86 emulator 

despite of them,there is no other options....

Comment: in that case, in that same list that I posted a picture of above, you need to scroll to the top of the list (In the Tools Folder) and install both "Android SDK Tools" as well as "Android SDK Platform-tools".  You need to install both of those, then restart the SDK manager (you may need to repeat this step until you have the newest version).  Mine is currently showing SDK Tools at 23.0.2 and Platform-tools at 20.  Make sure yours are up to date or you'll have other problems as well.